# Store data to a memory location in C

Tags: c

Is is possible to directly store data into a memory location using `C` ?

To be more specific,

What if i want to store an integer data to a memory location starting from `00100000`. Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes. Please don't do this. But yes. NOTE: my answer changes if you mean an actual *physical* address, rather than a virtual address.

Comment: You could `mmap()` the region containing the address... But you'd have to rely on the OS to actually honour your request.

Comment: also, there is no guarantee that whatever you pick isn't already in use...which will cause major problems. I can't think of an actual use case for this - what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: you know any computer you try this on has a virtual address space for userland programs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. You can do this: int*ptr = 00100000; And then do *(ptr) = 10; I highly recommend you don't do this however.